# How to effective start up time Kivy'App on Android

Tags: android, kivy

I'm interested to develop Android app via Kivy. But I've built Kivy App to run on Android, I've recognized it takes abouts 20-30 seconds to open a Kivy app. For example, this simple code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button 

class HelloApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello')

if __name__=='__main__':
    HelloApp().run()
```

I created a app package for Android. It's apk is very small, about 6MB. But it took about 20 seconds to open on my android phone, which ASUS ZENFONE 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main factor here is probably that the phone is quite slow, both in cpu and memory. This seems to be a big factor affecting kivy applications. For instance, on the nexus 4 it takes about 5s to start a simple app, and on the LG G4 it's very fast (maybe 1s or less).

Given this, there's probably not much you can do to improve it on that particular device.

One thing you could try, which might help a bit but probably wouldn't do *that* much, is to try the new SDL2 backend using the revamped python-for-android tools. This is faster than the pygame one, but not by that much, maybe 40% at most and that result depends on the hardware etc.